# Xamarin app crashes on ObservableCollection.Add?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have an Xamarin.Forms app running on iOS simulator that just stops as soon as it hits code which adds a new member to an observable collection that is the template source for a CarouselView.  Oddly, it doesnt happen immediately, but only when I add more items to the collection when the user gets close to the end of the carousel.  I can't trap the error in a try catch block.  In debug mode, when I stop at the line in question and either step in or step over, the app just closes and goes back to the home screen.  I recently updated my packages, maybe there is some issue there?

Code as follows:

```
private ObservableCollection<ResultsScroller> mySource;
public void PopulateResultsPages(List<NominalResult> resultList)
{
  foreach (var nr in resultList)
  {
    var template = new ResultsScroller();
    template.LoadData(nr);
    try
    {
       mySource.Add(template);    // <----app quits here
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
  }
  lastPosition = mySource.Count - 1;
}
```

Comment: Please post some error message about this exception. From your code, I can't capture the reason.

Comment: There is a bug open on crashing apps when adding items : https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59896 so could be you are hitting this

Answer (score 1):

initialize observablecollevtion mySource in constructor like this

```
mySource = new ObservableCollection<ResultsScroller>();
```

after that add item in it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have to somehow programmatically make the ListView appear before adding an item. If the ListView is inside a tab that is not visible, show it by setting the CurrentPage Property. If it is in a MasterDetailPage, you could try showing it by toggling the IsPresented Property.

An upcoming Update of XF should fix this issue:
- https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1542
- https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1927

Comment: This was helpful. It's currently not possible to add a record to a ObserableCollection attached to a CollectionView when it's hidden.